# convert query output into json format in sql server

Tags: json, sql-server

I want to display the below query output  into JSON Format(Required output format)

```
select ApplicationID ApplicationID ,Roleid Roles from UserRoles where userid=11 and applicationid is not null 

Output

ApplicationID  Roles
1                1
1                5
3                5
```

i want to display below format i am using sql server 2016

```
Required output Format:
[{"ApplicationID":1,"Roles":[1,5]},{"ApplicationID":3,"Roles":[5]}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you get with pure *T-SQL-JSON-support* will be this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ApplicationID INT,  Roles INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,1)
,(1,5)
,(3,5);

SELECT t.ApplicationID
      ,Roles.Roles AS Roles  
FROM @tbl t
INNER JOIN @tbl Roles ON Roles.ApplicationID=t.ApplicationID
GROUP BY t.ApplicationID,Roles.Roles
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

The result

```
[{"ApplicationID":1
 ,"Roles":[{"Roles":1}
          ,{"Roles":5}]
 }
,{"ApplicationID":3
 ,"Roles":[{"Roles":5}]}
]
```

In `AUTO` mode the engine will "see" the join and pack this into an *array of objects*.

Regretfully `FOR JSON` does not support *naked* arrays (`[1,2,3]`). You will always get *arrays of objects* like `[{Prop:Val},{Prop:Val},{Prop:Val}]`...

But you can out-trick this with a correlated sub-query and some string aggregation (We need `JSON_QUERY()` to avoid quotes around the array):

```
SELECT t.ApplicationID
      ,JSON_QUERY('[' + STUFF((
        SELECT CONCAT(',',Roles) 
        FROM @tbl t2
        WHERE t2.ApplicationID=t.ApplicationID
        FOR XML PATH('')
       ),1,1,'') + ']') AS Roles  
FROM @tbl t
GROUP BY t.ApplicationID
FOR JSON PATH;
```

The result

```
[{"ApplicationID":1,"Roles":[1,5]}
,{"ApplicationID":3,"Roles":[5]}]
```

Can you use `STRING_AGG()` (v2017+)? In this case you can simplify the sub-select.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016+, you can use `FOR JSON` statement

```
SELECT
    ApplicationID ApplicationID,
    Roleid Roles 
FROM UserRoles 
WHERE userid = 11 AND applicationid IS NOT NULL
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Take a look into this: [Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: above query gives output [{"ApplicationID":1,"Roles":1},{"ApplicationID":1,"Roles":5},{"ApplicationID":3,"Roles":5}]. if Application id exists more then once(example "ApplicationID:1 it should not come twice(without duplicates).Required output Format:
[{"ApplicationID":1,"Roles":[1,5]},{"ApplicationID":3,"Roles":[5]}]

Comment: Required output Format:
[{"ApplicationID":1,"Roles":[1,5]},{"ApplicationID":3,"Roles":[5]}]

Comment: CREATE TABLE USERROLES(ApplicationID int,Roleid INT)

Insert into userroles values(1,1);
insert into userroles values(1,5)
insert into userroles values(3,5)

Answer (score 0):

As I remember:

```
select ApplicationID ApplicationID ,Roleid Roles from UserRoles where userid=11 and applicationid is not null 
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT("UserRoles")
```